# Category menu column alignment css

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding to a custom build menu in Magento. The menu is working, but I don't really like the alignment of the items on the site. I will show you a picture of the menu now and below that the preferred version.

Picture now:
[image: Situation right now]

Preferred version (different site, but for the right feel):
[image: Preferred situation]

The website is [autoshopdirect.nl](https://www.autoshopdirect.nl). I'm not asking for the whole solution, but just something to get me started. It's is an ul with n the li's the following css:

```
   .nav-primary .child-container li.level1 {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        width: 190px;
        min-height: 138px;
        margin: 10px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
```

Comment: Hey you can drag and change the position of categories appearing from backend according to the layout suits. Also, i think you need to change the HTML structure as well. It will be helpful if you post it here.

Comment: Changing the position of categories never came up to me. That was exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css columns to achive this.

To the container of your items add `column-count: 4;` to define the number of columns you want.

On your item to avoid an item from breaking into a new column you need to add `column-break-inside: avoid;`. If you don't mind the menu breaking into the next column then just skip adding this part of the code.

Demonstration of result without **column-break-inside: avoid;**

```
Menu Header   menu-item     menu-item     Menu Header 
menu-item     menu-item     menu-item     menu-item
menu-item                   menu-item     menu-item
menu-item     Menu Header   menu-item     menu-item
menu-item     menu-item     menu-item     menu-item
```

---

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#content > .group {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  background-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-column-count: 4; //Defines the number of columns you want
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
#content > .group .item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#content > .group .item {
  padding: 10px;
  display: list-element;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -o-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -ms-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul class="group">
    <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      <br/>Subitem
    </li>
    <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>Subitem</li>
        <li>Subitem</li>
        <li>Subitem</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>Subitem</li>
        <li>Subitem</li>
        <li>Subitem</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><strong>Item</strong>
      </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: column-break-inside: avoid; helped me a lot. +1 for the enormous answer given ;)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2021**: You want to use these rules on the items in the list

```css
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
               break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
```